# How to access to BigQuery from pycharm installed on Local PC

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Newbie here, and wonder if there is a way for me to access to project of Google cloud from Local PC, and interact with the project on it ? Is there any AUTH involved it? I am using Pycharm, except the Python cloud client library which I have already installed it, I also install Google cloud SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this in Python, I would follow the instruction in here: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

You can find more detailed information about the Python client in:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html

Comment: Tim-Thank you. and can you please check my steps in Answers below ?

Comment: Amir-Thank you. and can you please check my steps in Answers below ?

Comment: Tim/Amir--Thank you,I realized that I only need to run the Google Cloud SDK and let it be, and even don't need to set the service account key file. It works. ..Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

What I did with following steps ,Please let me know if my steps are correct and I try to google more about the error something related with timeframe :

1. Creating a service account with following URL guide

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

2.Try to access to Bigquery with service account key :
 https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file

so my codes generally looks like :

from google.cloud import bigquery

```
def explicit():

    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('d:\hope-training-portal-2-3d15a04538e8.json')

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(bigquery_client.list_datasets())
    print(buckets)
```

but here comes error :
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/emma/PycharmProjects/GCP/INIT.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/emma/PycharmProjects/GCP/INIT.py", line 45, in

```
explicit()
```

File "C:/Users/emma/PycharmProjects/GCP/INIT.py", line 13, in explicit

```
buckets = list(bigquery_client.list_datasets())
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\iterator.py", line 218, in _items_iter

```
for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\iterator.py", line 248, in _page_iter

```
page = self._next_page()
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\iterator.py", line 348, in _next_page

```
response = self._get_next_page_response()
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\iterator.py", line 399, in _get_next_page_response

```
query_params=params)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 290, in api_request

```
headers=headers, target_object=_target_object)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 183, in _make_request

```
return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_http.py", line 212, in _do_request

```
url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 176, in request

```
self._auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\auth\credentials.py", line 121, in before_request

```
self.refresh(request)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 310, in refresh

```
request, self._token_uri, assertion)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2_client.py", line 143, in jwt_grant

```
response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2_client.py", line 109, in _token_endpoint_request

```
_handle_error_response(response_body)
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2_client.py", line 59, in _handle_error_response

```
error_details, response_body)

google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe', u'{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description" : "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe"\n}')
```